# Sql 2008 r2. Nvarchar(50) how many size does it consume on the Hard drive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

im trying to build a program with so many transaction and inputs. the columns is only nvarchar(50). i want to know how much size does it consume in my hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what data you store in it. If you store a null or an empty string, it will take around 2 bytes. If you use all 50 characters, it will take around 102 bytes. See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: ... and if you enable data compression (row or higher) and many of the regular characters will only require one byte instead of two bytes. Data compression required Enterprise Edition prior to SQL Server 2016 sp1.